# Import all modules in django

Tags: django, python, django-settings

In django is there way to import all modules

```
   ex: from project.models import *
   ex: from project1.models import *
```

Can this be done with one statement

Comment: When testing the code if there is a need of importing three or 4 modules into python prompt this would come in handy..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to do this when testing things in the shell, look into the `shell_plus` command provided by the [django-extensions](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/) project.

This is a really neat extension, which starts a shell and automatically loads all the models in your project when you do `./manage.py shell_plus` from the command line.

Comment: +1 - Also, you might find the way they load all models instructive (see http://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py)